# Proper handling of disabled/readonly textboxes for accessibility

Tags: android, html, ios, iphone, accessibility

I have an issue where iphone VoiceOver or Android Voice Assistant on mobile devices state "double tap to edit" no matter what I try.  I've been told it should not state "double tap to edit" which makes sense to me.

I created a CodePen and no combo seems to work on iphone and android: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oQJvEr

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Readonly Textbox:

```
<input type="text" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" value="1" readonly>
```

Disabled Textbox:

```
<input type="text" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" value="1" disabled>
```

Readonly=Readonly Textbox:

```
<input type="text" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" value="1" readonly="readonly">
```

Readonly=Readonly+Aria Textbox:

```
<input type="text" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" value="1" readonly="readonly" aria-readonly="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

That's annoying.  Voiceover tells me the input field is readonly but still tells me to double tab to edit.  That seems like a bug in Voiceover and you should report it to Apple.

When I double tap, it tells me "insertion point at end", but since the field is readonly, the onscreen keyboard does not show up.  That's a very confusing scenario.

However, when I tried your four cases, the "disabled" input (2nd example) worked correctly.  It did **not** tell me to double tap to edit.

Also, based on `disabled` working, I got your other cases to work if I added `aria-disabled="true"`.

Comment: It is annoying!  What's worse is ALL the examples say "double tap to edit" on my Android.  I feel I might be missing something here since both iphone and android do this but it really doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: did `aria-disabled="true"` work on android?  it works on voiceover

Comment: Nope. I tried adding it to all the examples and none work.  I'll let Apple and Google know as you suggested because this is very odd...

Comment: sounds like no solution for android at the moment.  too bad.  at least you can get voiceover working, and since most visually impaired users use an ios device rather than android, hopefully you'll cover a large segment of that audience.